# Adding moisture to gluten free muffins

Tags: gluten-free, moisture

I am using the following list of ingredients in trying to make gluten free, grain free, egg free, sugar free muffins. The texture turned out a bit too dry. Increasing which ingredient would give a moister texture? Bananas or date puree?

- 1/2 cup Buckwheat flour
- 1/2 cup Potato starch
- 1 teaspoon baking soda
- 1/4 cup melted butter
- 1/3 cup date puree
- 1/2 cup mashed ripe bananas
- 1/4 cup yogurt
- Pinch of cinnamon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing the amount of yogurt and/or banana mash should work best, the former having a more noticeable difference. You might have to experiment to get the amount right, but I'd suggest starting with an additional 1/4 cup of yogurt or banana mash. You could try more date puree as well but that might make the muffins too thick.

Answer (score -2):

Also don't forget to add moisture into the oven by placing a bowl of water in the oven when baking.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the moisture perception within the muffin.